# Sampling Distribution of Sample Correlation Coefficient

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, estimation, multivariate-analysis, autocorrelation

For a linear process $X_t=\mu+\sum_j\varphi_jW_{t-j}$

where $W_t$ is white noise and $\mathbb E(W_t^4)<\infty$ ,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
       \hat\rho(1) \\
       \hat\rho(2) \\
\vdots \\
       \hat\rho(k) \\
        \end{pmatrix}     
\sim AN \begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
       \rho(1) \\
       \rho(2) \\
\vdots \\
       \rho(k) \\
\end{pmatrix},\frac{1}{n}V
        \end{pmatrix}  $$

Where $$V_{i,j}=\sum_{h=1}^{\infty}(\rho(h+i)+\rho(h-i)-2\rho(i)\rho(h))\times(\rho(h+j)+\rho(h-j)-2\rho(j)\rho(h))$$

And $AN$ denotes *Asymptotic Normal*.

- My first question is , why is the variance of $\rho=\frac{1}{n}V$ , that is , why have we multiplied $\frac{1}{n}$ with $V$ ?
- How does the formula of $V_{i,j}$ come ?

Comment: It's Theorem 7.2.1. from *Time Series: Theory and Methods* by P. Brockwell and R. Davis, a very thorough proof is given in section 7.3 there.